# PostgreSQL custom type + Hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, mapping

I am using PostgreSQL (9.1) and Hibernate (4.1.4). I want to map my custom PostgreSQL type into object in Hibernate.
I've created type in PostgreSQL like this:

```
create type nill_int as (value int8, nill varchar(100));
```

Now I want to map this type on Hibernate:

```
package my;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.type.IntegerType;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;
import org.hibernate.usertype.CompositeUserType;

public class PGNillableIntegerType implements CompositeUserType {

    @Override
    public String[] getPropertyNames() {
        return new String[] {"value","nill"};
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getPropertyTypes() {
        return new Type[] {IntegerType.INSTANCE, StringType.INSTANCE};
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPropertyValue(Object component, int property)
            throws HibernateException {
        if( component == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        final NillableInteger nillable = (NillableInteger)component;
        switch (property) {
            case 0: {
                return nillable.getValue();
            }
            case 1: {
                return nillable.getNill();
            }
            default: {
                throw new HibernateException("Invalid property index [" + property + "]");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setPropertyValue(Object component, int property, Object value)
            throws HibernateException {
        if(component == null)
            return;

        final NillableInteger nillable = (NillableInteger) component;
        switch (property) {
            case 0: {
                nillable.setValue((Integer)value);
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                nillable.setNill((String)value);
                break;
            }
            default: { 
                throw new HibernateException("Invalid property index [" + property + "]");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names,
            SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        assert names.length == 2;
        Integer value = (Integer) IntegerType.INSTANCE.get(rs, names[0], session);
        String nill = (String) StringType.INSTANCE.get(rs, names[1], session);

        return new NillableInteger(value, nill);
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index,
            SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if(value == null) {
            IntegerType.INSTANCE.set(st, null, index, session);
            StringType.INSTANCE.set(st, null, index + 1, session);
        } else {
            final NillableInteger nillable = (NillableInteger)value;
            IntegerType.INSTANCE.set(st, nillable.getValue(), index, session);
            StringType.INSTANCE.set(st, nillable.getNill(), index + 1, session);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return NillableInteger.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return ObjectUtils.equals(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        assert (x != null);
        return x.hashCode();
    }



    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, SessionImplementor session,
            Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target,
            SessionImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }


}
```

and use this in my entity:

```
package my;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;


@Entity
@Table(name = "test_test")
public class TestObj {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "IdGenerator")
    @TableGenerator(
        name = "IdGenerator",
        pkColumnValue = "test",
        table="SeqTable",
        allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
    private Long id;

    private String test;

    @Type(type = "my.PGNillableIntegerType")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "nill_int")
//  @Columns(columns = {
//          @Column(name = "val"),
//          @Column(name = "reason")
//  })
    private NillableInteger nill;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public NillableInteger getNill() {
        return nill;
    }

    public void setNill(NillableInteger nill) {
        this.nill = nill;
    }

}
```

where `NillableInteger` looks like this:

```
package my;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

public class NillableInteger {

    private Integer value;
    private String nill;

    public NillableInteger() {

    }

    public NillableInteger(String str) {
        str = str.substring(1,str.length()-1);
        String[] splitted = str.split(",");
        value = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);
        nill = splitted[1];
    }

    public NillableInteger(Integer value, String nill) {
        this.value = value;
        this.nill = nill;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + value + "," + nill + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((nill == null) ? 0 : nill.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        NillableInteger other = (NillableInteger) obj;
        if (nill == null) {
            if (other.nill != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nill.equals(other.nill))
            return false;
        if (value == null) {
            if (other.value != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String getNill() {
        return nill;
    }
    public void setNill(String nill) {
        this.nill = nill;
    }
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

This configuration throws something like this:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: my.TestObj.nill type: my.PGNillableIntegerType
```

Everything works fine when I use `@Columns` annotation instead of `@Column` in the `TestObj`, but this creates two separate columns in `test_test` table (`TestObj` mapping table) with types `integer` and `character varying(255)`. What I want to achieve is that in the table will be one column with type `nill_int` (created custom PostgreSQL type) and Java objects will looks like above.
Any ideas?
Thanks, Arek

Comment: Full and explained solution in this link [network postgres types on hibernate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019866/hibernate-postgresql-network-address-type-inet-cdir/22759209#22759209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I've done to achieve above goal: I've changed my type to something which looks like this:

```
package my;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;


public class PGNillableIntegerType implements UserType {

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.OTHER };
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return NillableInteger.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names,
            SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        return new NillableInteger(rs.getString(names[0]));
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index,
            SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if(value == null) {
            st.setObject(index, null, Types.OTHER);
        } else {
            final NillableInteger nillable = (NillableInteger)value;
            st.setObject(index, nillable.toString(), Types.OTHER);
//          IntegerType.INSTANCE.set(st, nillable.getValue(), index, session);
//          StringType.INSTANCE.set(st, nillable.getNill(), index + 1, session);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object arg0, Object arg1) throws HibernateException {
        return arg0.equals(arg1);
    }

    public int hashCode(Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return object.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }



}
```

Now you can use `@Column` with PostgreSQL type in `columnDefinition`. Unfortunately, the problem are queries to hibernate (after some searching - I think the only way is to use SQL queries [like this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=933883) - if anyone knows how to do this with HQL or criteria it would be great...).

Comment: Any idea how to implement NillableInteger[] ?