# Hibernate + PostgreSQL + Network Address Type (inet, cdir)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I have started my example project with Hibernate 4.2.7 and PostgreSQL 9.3.1 and everything is going well.

At the moment I would like to use [INET PostgreSQL type](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_data_types.htm) but I am not able to map it with Hibernate.

I got this hibernate error: **Could not determine type for: inet, at table: DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS, for columns...**

I use *org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect* and hbm.xml configuratiin files.

My hibernate mapping file:

```
<property name="ipAddress" type="inet">
     <column name="IP_ADDRESS" not-null="true" />
</property>
```

I asked the google but I could not find any usable solution.
Could you help me?

Thx!

EDIT:
What do you think what kind of ORM implementation do I need to use if I want to use the 'extra' postgresql types and [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) types?

Or I need to use the simple JDBC?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/The-Alchemist/hibernate-postgresql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/thealchemist/pg_hibernate/InetAddressType.java?

Comment: I do not use Hibernate anymore. I use MyBatis instead of Hibernate. It fits better to my requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced similar problem recently with Hibernate 3 & Postgres 9. Since there was no inbuilt mapping provided for String Array in postgres to Java String[] by hibernate, I end up implementing a custom mapping class. You can try following below steps.

1. Create Custom class "PgInet" which implements "org.hibernate.usertype.UserType" (this UserType class is per my hibernate 3 knowledge. Not sure if this has been changed in Hibernate 4).
2. Below method implementation would be critical.

   - equals
   - nullSafeGet
   - nullSafeSet
   - returnedClass
     return InetAddress.class;
   - sqlTypes
     return new int[] {java.sql.Types.}

Once above is done, we just need to set type of property in HBM.xml to this class i.e. PgInet.

For custom class implementation try referring to existing type implementation class. You should be able to locate class files. Use below link as reference.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/hibernate/hibernate/2.1.8/net/sf/hibernate/type/ArrayType.java

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I just solve a problem like yours.There is little info about this matter. As @ms03 said...better way is create a new type and a class which implements this type and handler the java object for setting/ getting on database.

First on your entity you must declare types for yours params.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_app")
@TypeDefs(value={@TypeDef(name="convertInet",typeClass=PgInetType.class),
         @TypeDef(name="convertMacaddr",typeClass=PgMacaddrType.class)})
public class User implements Serializable {

    //some parameters

  @Type(type="convertMacaddr")
  private PgMacaddr mac;

  @Type(type="convertInet")
  private PgInet ip;

     //getters and setters, equals, hashcode, toString
  }
```

Second create the new object handled for java, it must got a default construct, a construct to handler data from DB and to be Seriarizable.

```
public class PgInet implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String address;

public PgInet(String address){
    this.address=address;
}

public PgInet(){
    this.address=null;
}

    //Getters,setters,hashcode, equal and toString
 }
```

And final step you must create a custom type

```
public class PgInetType implements UserType{

@Override
public int[] sqlTypes() {

            //Because inet,macaddr,cdir...and unkwon type for java, yo must
            // define Types.OTHER
    return new int[] { Types.OTHER };
}

@Override
public Class returnedClass() {

            //Object created to be handled for java
    return PgInet.class;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
    return ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(x, y);
}

@Override
public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
    if(x!=null)
        return x.hashCode();
    else
        return 0;
}

@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names,
        SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {

            //Translation from DB to Java
    PgInet address=null;

    String ip=rs.getString(names[0]);

    if(ip!=null){
        address=new PgInet(ip);
    }

    return address;
}

@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index,
        SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    //Translation from java to DB

    if(value==null){
        st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
    }else{

                //As inet,macaddr,cdir...are new types object on Postgresql you must
                //create the specific postgresql object and to insert it

                //I created 2 new cast on postgresql: inet As varchar, varchar AS inet
                //but I think it's not neccesary because macaddr type works fine without
                //postgresl casting

        st.setObject(index, getInet(value, st.getConnection()));
    }

}

private Object getInet(Object value, Connection connection) {

           //Expected object on postgresql

       Object tempInet = null;
       ClassLoader connectionClassLoader = connection.getClass().getClassLoader();

       try {

           //Class which will create the postgresql

           Class aPGObjectClass =connectionClassLoader.loadClass("org.postgresql.util.PGobject");
           Constructor ct = aPGObjectClass.getConstructor(null);
           try {
            tempInet = ct.newInstance(null);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

           Method setTypeMethod = aPGObjectClass.getMethod("setType", new Class[]{String.class});
           try {

               //Setting postgresql type, inet in this case

            setTypeMethod.invoke(tempInet, new Object[]{"inet"});
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

           Method setValueMethod = aPGObjectClass.getMethod("setValue", new Class[]{String.class});
           try {
            setValueMethod.invoke(tempInet, new Object[]{value.toString()});
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

       } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

       return tempInet;
   }

@Override
public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    if(value==null)
        return null;
    else{
        PgInet PgInetNew=new PgInet();
        PgInet PgInetOriginal=(PgInet)value;

        PgInetNew.setAddress(PgInetOriginal.getAddress());

        return PgInetNew;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isMutable() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
     Object  deepCopy=deepCopy(value);

      if(!(deepCopy instanceof Serializable))
       return (Serializable)deepCopy;

      return null;
}

@Override
public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException {
    return deepCopy(cached);
}

@Override
public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException {
    return deepCopy(original);
}

 }
```

This way works fine for me when I insert or get a row from DB.

Comment: not working for me. throws `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type cidr: "com.xxx.yyy.model.PgCidrType`. i'm using jpa though...