# PostgreSQL network types in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I want to use Postgresql network data type of mac address (macaddr) in Hibernate ORM. How could I map macaddr type to a entity class property? What is the best way of doing so? I never used non standard SQL types in Hibernate

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solve a problem like this,so I insert and get row from DB postgresql 9 successfully. The solution explained completely is in this link [network postgres types on hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019866/hibernate-postgresql-network-address-type-inet-cdir/22759209#22759209)

Answer (score 2):

Mac address is a String.  If it's a @OneToOne relationship between the mac address and its user, then you don't have to make an entity class out of simple strings, just include it as a field on whatever entity needs it, like so:

```
private String macAddress;
```

If the same mac address is used by multiple entities and you want to reuse the value (normalize), then you'd make an entity like this:

```
package com.acme.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MacAddress implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1l;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String value;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mac Address is not "a String". In Postgres it's an own datatype with its own distinct operators. It's used to define columns in tables, not to create entities (tables)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the mac-address is never totaly validated, there is no Standard-Type in Java. You can use

```
@ColumnTransformer(read="CAST(mac AS varchar)", write="CAST(? AS macaddr)") String
```

instead to read/write it as String.

Comment: you can't cast mac As varchar because they aren't compatibles binaries types. I guess you'll need first to create a function, and then a cast using the function.